How to integrate paypal in react native
I am trying to integrate paypal in my react native app. I tried the REST API method as per the paypal docs directly in the app (RN frontend) and its working. Below is the code
Button component
let baseUrl = 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com';
.....
...
    <ButtonComp
      onPress={onPressPaypal}
      disabled={false}
      btnStyle={{backgroundColor: '#0f4fa3', marginVertical: 16}}
      text="PayPal"
      isLoading={isLoading}
    />

on press function
const onPressPaypal = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const token = await paypalApi.generateToken();
      const res = await paypalApi.createOrder(token);
      setAccessToken(token);
     
      setLoading(false);
      if (!!res?.links) {
        const findUrl = res.links.find(data => data?.rel == 'approve');
        setPaypalUrl(findUrl.href);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

But instead this direct implementation in the frontend, I need to setup a node/express backend and create endpoints and consume those endpoints in the frontend (react native app). Is it possible ? or I need to directly use the paypal api in frontend ? Is there any npm packages for this implementation ?
I see there is one package called react-native-paypal but its not maintained

create/capture routes should be on a web hosted backend. Client ID, Secret, and resulting access_token should never pass through RN in any way.

@ Preston PHX what is correct method to implement this in React Native app ? can u suggest some method ?

The correct method is to use RN only for the frontend and display of the button. For security Create/Capture API operations should not be done from RN; use any web-based backend the RN app can communicate with

Thank you but in React Native there is no well maintained SDK that can be used, so thats why confused on the integration process.

You may be looking for something like https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-ios so that the JS SDK (via paypal-react-js or whatever) can open its approval window

Okay will check that
